# How would one evaluate the following complex integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

The integral is:

$$\int_0^1\frac{-2i}{(2t-1)+i}\ dt$$

After some manipulation, I got it to the form:

$$\int_0^1\frac{i-1-2it}{2t^2-2t+1}\ dt$$

but have no idea how to proceed.

How do you evaluate this above-mentioned integral?

Note: I know the answer already which is -$\pi/2$.

Comment: @avs Residue theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can be very direct in the integration.

$\int_0^1\frac{-2i}{(2t-1)+i}\ dt\\
-i\ln (2t-1+i)|_0^1\\
-i\ln (1+i) + i\ln (-1+i)$

I am just treating the complex constants as constants.

$1+i = \sqrt 2 e^{\frac {\pi}{4}i}\\
-1+i = \sqrt 2 e^{\frac {3\pi}{4}i}$

$-i(\frac {\pi}{4}i) - \frac{i}{2}\ln 2 + i(\frac {3\pi}{4}i)+\frac{i}{2}\ln 2\\
-\frac {\pi}{2}$

Comment: yeah, why should it be any different for complex numbers?

Comment: Thank you. I'm still relatively new at performing integration with complex numbers so the i through me off.

Comment: well, integration looks at rate of change and i is a constant. It should be intuitive but sometimes calculus is taught badly and i can understand that

Comment: sorry, no i made the mistake @DougM

Answer (score 1):

Since -2i is a constant maybe you should integrate the denominator and hence you will get the answer -ilog(2t-1+i) , then after inserting the limits you will get 
-i(log(i+1)-log(i-1))= -ilog(-i)= -ilog(-1)-ilogi =-i(iπ)+π/2=3π/2

Comment: that's right but you need to be careful in plugging in the right values

Comment: I think the answer should be -$\pi/2$

Comment: How please explain it will be very kind of you

Comment: @Angad look at Doug M's answer above. He goes through the full workings and gets the figure I quoted.